# Orders not being created with recurring profile products in magento

Tags: recurring

I had a customer sign up for a reccurring profile product and they checked out using Paypal as a payment method.

Magento created a Recurring Payment Profile for her to be charged once a month, but it did not create an order.

For orders placed using our other payment methods a recurring payment profile is created as is an order.

Is there something I need to configure further with Paypal/Magento to have the order and profile created? Has anyone else had this issue?